# Why does `tail -f /var/audit/current | praudit` just print 5 lines and exit immediately?

Tags: macos, bash, tail, auditd, darwin

I want to follow my audit log live so I can watch for events, and pipe it through praudit to make it human readable. All commands below are run as root.

When I run `tail -f /var/audit/current | praudit` is just prints the last 5 lines and immediately exits. Whereas `tail -f /var/audit/current | cat` waits and prints out the raw audit log as it is written. What is the essential difference between `praudit` and `cat`? They both claim to read from stdin which they both appear to do, except `praudit` just gives up without waiting for an EOF? Or something?

Would love to know why this is the case, and if there's a way to get the behaviour I want somehow, preferably without having to modify praudit...

I'm on macOS 10.14.3

Comment: So, I found a tool that lets me stream realtime audit logs from /dev/auditpipe instead: http://newosxbook.com/tools/supraudit.html still curious on the oddities of praudit not waiting on more input though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to achieve what you need without the additional commands (meaning `cat` and `praudit`).

Simply issuing `tail -f /var/audit/current` will give you the last 10 lines, and wait for further output.

**EDIT1:**
Ok, I see why you want to use praudit. Wasn't familiar with this command myself.

**EDIT2:**
Try this:
`sudo praudit /dev/auditpipe`

> Audit pipes are cloning pseudo-devices in the device file system which
>   allow applications to tap the live audit record stream. This is
>   primarily of interest to authors of intrusion detection and system
>   monitoring applications. However, for the administrator the audit pipe
>   device is a convenient way to allow live monitoring without running
>   into problems with audit trail file ownership or log rotation
>   interrupting the event stream.

Comment: Did you actually try `sudo praudit /dev/auditpipe` ? It doesn't work without opening the file specially using ioctls. See comment on the question above, there is a tool supraudit which can open that file sending the right ioctls to actually get output.